# ReactJS - Accessing data on Different Pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I am trying to access data gathered from a user on one page and use it on another page. I have tried following these articles:

> https://travishorn.com/passing-data-between-classes-components-in-react-4f8fea489f80
>
> https://medium.com/@ruthmpardee/passing-data-between-react-components-103ad82ebd17
>
> https://codeburst.io/react-js-pass-data-from-components-8965d7892ca2

I have not been able to get it to work. `this.props.{variableName}`keeps returning as undefined. My code is as follows.

The following is the Home Page:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Button} from 'reactstrap';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

class HomeScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      working: "",
    };
  }

  WorkReqNav(){
    this.setState=({working: "WORKING"});
    browserHistory.push("/WorkReq");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button size="lg" onClick={this.WorkReqNav.bind(this)} type='button'>HIT IT!</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

The following is the workReq screen:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Button} from 'reactstrap';

class WorkReq extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  workCheck(){
    var working = this.props.working;
    alert(working);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button size="lg" onClick={this.workCheck.bind(this)} type='button'>HIT IT!</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default WorkReq;
```

If you need anything more, please let me know. i am really new to React and this is my first time attempting anything like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

welcome to the React world. I bet you'll love it when you gradually get familiar with cool stuff that you can do with React. Just be patient and keep practicing.

So the first suggestion I would make is that, like any other javascript environment, React also evolves very quickly. So although basic principles are the same, when you follow a new article on one hand, on the other hand you can check if the libraries or methodologies that are demonstrated are up to date.

Fasten your belts and let's do a quick review based on your question and libraries that I see you used in your example.

In terms of router, I see that you directly export things from `react-router`
When we check the npm page (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router) of react-router they make the following suggestion

> If you are writing an application that will run in the browser, you
>   should instead install react-router-dom

Which is the following package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom
You can get more details and find more tutorials in order to improve your skills by checking their official page https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/philosophy

Let's take a look at the code snippet sasha romanov provided that's based on `react-router-dom` syntax

with `react-router-dom` when you define a route with following syntax

```
<Route path="/" component={HomePage} exact />
```

`react-router-dom` automatically passes `match`, `location`, and `history` props to `HomePage` component. So when you `console.log()` these props, you should be able to display somethings on your console. And once you have access to `history` props, instead of `browserHistory`, you can use `this.props.history.push("/some-route")` for redirections.

Let's take a look at the part related to `withRouter`. In the example above, we could use `history` because `HomePage` component was passed directly to the `Router` component that we extract from `react-router-dom`. However, in real life, there might be cases in which you want to use `history` props in a component that's not passed to the `Router` but let's say just a reusable button component. For these cases, `react-router-dom` provides a Higher Order Component called `withRouter`

A Higher Order Component is (from React's official documentation)
https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

> Concretely, a higher-order component is a function that takes a
>   component and returns a new component.

So basically, whenever you wrap any component with `withRouter` such as `export default withRouter(MyWrappedReusableComponent)`, in your reusable component, you will have access to the props `history`, `location`, `pathname`

That said, my first impression regarding to your problem does not seem to be related to router logic but rather exchanging data between components.

In your original question, you mentioned that

```
I am trying to access data gathered from a user on one page and use it on another page
```

There are a couple of cases/ways to approach this issue

1) If these two components are completely irrelevant, you can use state management system such as `Redux`, `mobx` or you can use React's context API https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html. HOWEVER, since you are new to React, I would suggest not tackle with these right know till you are comfortable with the basic flow. Because at some point trying to implement a flow with a lot of libraries etc. is quite overwhelming. Believe me, I tried when I was also new to React and I was really close to break my computer after opening my 100th browser tab to look for another method from another library

2) You can implement a simple parent-child relationship to pass data between components. Let me explain what I mean by using references from your code snippet.

I believe you want to update `working` which is a state in your `HomeScreen` and you want to pass and use this updated value in your `WorkReq` component.

If we ignore all the routing logic and decide to go without routes, what you need to do is the following

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Button} from 'reactstrap';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import WorkReqComponent from 'path/to/WorkReqDirectory';


class HomeScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      working: "WORKING",
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <WorkReqComponent working={this.state.working} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

By this way, when you log `this.props.working;` in your `WorkReqComponent` you should be able to display the data that you passed. You can refer to this as `passing data from parent to child`.

I checked the articles you listed. They also seem to explain data transfer between `parent to child`, `child to parent` or `between siblings`.

In your case, what you really need to implement can be categorized as `between siblings`

I prepared a sample for you with `react-router-dom` to demonstrate one possible structure which might yield your expected outcome.
https://codesandbox.io/s/ojp2y0xxo6

In this example, the state is defined inside of the parent component called `App`. Also state update logic is also defined inside of the parent component. `HomeScreen` and `WorkReq` components are the children of `App` thus they are siblings. So, in order to transfer data between siblings, one of them was given the task of updating parent's state via passing state update logic to this component. The other one has the task of displaying parent's state's value.

At this point, since you are new and in order not to overwhelm yourself, you can experiment with `parent-child-sibling` data transfer topic. Once you are getting comfortable with the implementation and the logic, you can gradually start taking a look at React's context api and Redux/mobx.

Let me know if you have any questions regarding to the sample I provided

Comment: Thanks, I am understanding this a lot better now, I just have one question, I have changed a few things around and now in my `app.js`, there are only my routes. Every page is stored in a different file. when i try to access the `props.working` in `workReq`, I get `'props' is not defined`. I would create a code pen but when i tried, i couldn't get my code to run...

Comment: Actually it'd be great if you could provide me a code sample (let's say with codesandbox). It doesn't matter if your code runs or not. I need to check the current structure of app/files and how data passing is handled. Otherwise it's a bit hard for me to provide a feedback that might solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

You can use react-router-dom lib and from seeing your code i think in parent component (app.js) you defined route for each child component you'd like to access
like this example here:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

<BrowserRouter>
  <div>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={HomePage} exact />
        <Route path="/homescreen" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Route path="/workreq" render={(props) => <WorkReq {...props} />} /> // here you can pass the props by calling render
        <Route component={NoMatch} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

and then if you want to change route you can just call `this.props.history.push('/workreq')`

and if you didn't include route for the component in `<BrowserRouter />`

in the component that it's not included you can import withRouter and export like this `withRouter(HomeScreen)` and now you can access router props

if this isn't the answer you are looking please inform me to update my answer, i hope this can help

Comment: Your guess is write, sorry I probably should have included my router code. My router stuff is done is a separate file called router.js but looks like what you have above. Could you provide an example of this working? (I am not quite understanding `withRouter` part.

Comment: @ChristopherLittlewood the onus is on you to provide a reproducible example. Either link us to your code on github or create a codepen with the issue and then we can help get it working if you're still stuck. You'll get a better response with a specific problem than 'here-is-my-code-make-it-work'. If you don't have a specific problem then you need tutorials, not stackoverflow. Try more recent tutorials, you're looking at writeups from 2016/17, that's decades in react years.